¿Cómo se puede conbinar una cadena de texto de una variable en Latino?
Soy un programador pequeño que esta aprendiendo Phyton, C++, C#, Java y Latino. En este ultimo lenguaje tengo un problema, no sé combinar una cadena de texto con una variable en una misma línea. Te agradecería mucho la respuesta.
Este es mi código en cuestión.
escribir ("Ingresa tu nombre")

Nombre = leer()

escribir("Hola, ")


¿te refieres a escribir("hola, "..Nombre)?

Revisando la documentación, disponible en el sitio web, nos encontramos con lo siguiente:
Concatenar cadenas(textos)
Para concatenar o unir textos en Latino se hace uso de doble puntos (..), que a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación los cuales usan el signo de más (+).
El doble punto (..) no solo es útil para unir textos, también números.
x = "Hola mundo"
y = ", Latino"
escribir(x..y)     //Devolverá Hola mundo, Latino
escribir(1..2)     //Devolverá 12

Fuente: https://manual.lenguajelatino.org/es/stable/sintaxis/Cadenas.html
Aplicando a tu caso particular
escribir ("Ingresa tu nombre")

Nombre = leer()

escribir("Hola, "..Nombre)


Ah, muchas gracias y también me surge otra duda, al concatenar las cadenas y variables me sale pero cuando quiero hacer concatenar dos variables van juntas cuando debería de haber un espacio entre medio.escribir("Selecciona tu nombre")
Nombre = leer()
escribir("\nHola, ".. Nombre)
escribir("\nSelecciona tu apellido")
Apellido = leer()
escribir("Hola, "..Nombre .. Apellido)

No tengo Latino, pero apostaría que escribir("Hola, "..Nombre .. " " .. Apellido) es lo que buscas.
